# Replacing Docker IMAGE TAGS

Tags: bash, docker, sed

I am trying to replace the docker image tag using the below script. However, the tag i.e. 1.2.4.3 is read as a special char by sed. Hence, in the output inside the docker-compose file, I get tags replaced as {version} and not 1.2.4.3

```
#!/bin/bash
dc_path=“/srv/salt/tm/files”
version=$1
cd ${dc_path}
sed -i.back ‘/image:/s/:[0-9].*/:${version}/g’ docker-compose.yaml
```

Calling the script as test.sh 1.2.4.3

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes: ```sed -i.back "/image:/s/:[0-9].*/:${version}/g" docker-compose.yaml```

Comment: Thanks that works!